# Can't force focus on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

I'm trying to focus an `input` after clicking in a `span`, the `input` isn't visible, but when I click in the `span` it becomes visible

```
<form action="{{ route('busca') }}" method="get">
    <span class="pesquisa-icon"></span>
    <input id="q" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Digite o que precisa e pressione ENTER..."/>
</form>
```

With jQuery I become the input visible

```
$(this).closest('.menu').addClass('pesquisa-open');
$(this).siblings('input').focus();
```

but it doesn't become focused, even in the browser, I tried `$('#q').focus()` in browser console (with the input visible) and it doesn't focus.

I'm using Opera Browser

**SOLUTION**

I checked Sebastian Speitel answer as correct answer cause it is helpful, but my problem actually was in css, my input was with the property `visibility: hidden` and even I changing to `visibility: visible` after clicking on `span` it didn't focus, removing this property solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the same functionality, `<label>`s are for. You can simply implement one by enclosing your `<span>` and `<input>` in one.

Read more about them here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 1):

It works using only `.focus()`.

See this demo:

```js
$('.pesquisa-icon').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next().addClass('shown').focus();
});
```

```css
#q{
  display: none;
}

#q.shown{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
    <span class="pesquisa-icon">TEST</span>
    <input id="q" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Digite o que precisa e pressione ENTER..."/>
</form>
```